# Does ginger grow well indoors?

Tags: houseplants, indoors, ginger

I'm considering growing some ginger on my window-ledge. Is ginger a hardy plant that is conducive to indoor cultivation? Also, will ginger root from the supermarket grow?

Answer (score 11):

It grows well as a forced plant indoors, and will grow year after year if the rest period and fertilizer needs are met. The roots from the supermarket usually work but may have been sprayed by a growth inhibitor to keep them from sprouting. Make sure they have large containers and plenty of light. Rotating the pots once a week keeps them from growing one sided.

Answer (score 6):

To add to jmusser's answer; I've had no problems growing grocery ginger (perhaps I was lucky with the growth inhibitor). You need a piece that is larger than about an inch and with complete "buds" or "wrinkles" (they look like wrinkles in the side of the ginger root).
Plant it horizontally - iirc I planted mine about 1-2in deep. And as jmusser says, use a large, deep pot.

I suspect my location lacked enough sun, but I believe my big mistake was not watering it frequently enough. When the plant died back I dug it up. The original root had been absorbed (rather like a seed potato does), but it had been replaced by lots of tap roots. These are vertical pointy things. So I think it was reaching down for water.